# How to convert the html book into a pdf (with bookmarks for toc)?

Tags: linux, pdf, html, bookmarks, ebook

I downloaded a large HTML-formatted reference document, which contains a number of chapters in separate files.  I would like to convert the entire document into a single PDF file, preferably with a table of contents that links directly to each chapter.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm looking for a solution that will work in Linux.

Comment: As this is constructed it is a "shopping request", a recommendation for a product or service. Because these answers vary widely and can changed based on preference, and may be best answered in an extended discussion, they are off-topic for superuser.

Comment: @music2myear; really? I doubt that you can give more than one recommendations.

Comment: Yes, really. An on-topic question would be "I'm working with X software trying to do Y, and it's breaking or not working at Z. Here's what I've tried. Here's the symptoms." A question that is "What product or service can do Y" is a shopping request.